# News Feed Issue

Tags: support, rss

[image]

I accidentally clicked the news feed button at the bottom of the page while browsing questions and to my surprise it showed me this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:re="http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0">
    <title type="text">Recent Questions - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="self" href="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds" type="application/atom+xml" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions" type="text/html" />
    <subtitle>most recent 30 from stackoverflow.com</subtitle>
    <updated>2014-09-05T11:08:33Z</updated>
    <id>http://stackoverflow.com/feeds</id>
    <creativeCommons:license>http://www.creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/rdf</creativeCommons:license> 
    <entry>
        <id>http://stackoverflow.com/q/25684533</id>
        <re:rank scheme="http://stackoverflow.com">0</re:rank>
        <title type="text">Neo4j support for deferred constraints</title>
            <category scheme="http://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="neo4j" />
            <category scheme="http://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="cypher" />
        <author>
            <name>Mehul</name>
            <uri>http://stackoverflow.com/users/3936095</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="alternate" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684533/neo4j-support-for-deferred-constraints" />
        <published>2014-09-05T11:08:07Z</published>
        <updated>2014-09-05T11:08:07Z</updated>
        <summary type="html">


            &lt;p&gt;Suppose that for certain nodes, attributes have unique constraints defined on them.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;When cloning nodes, we copy properties from original to cloned node and then modify the unique attributes on the cloned node.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;However, neo4j exhibits eager constraint evaluation and seems to fail as soon as unique properties are replicated from original to cloned node.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Is there are way to differ the constraint evaluation to the end of the transaction?&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Or some workaround that can mitigate the problem for the timebeing.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Sample cypher for illustrating the problem:&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;ol&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Create unique constraint for nodes labelled y on attribute id.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;create constraint on (y:y) assert y.id is unique;
&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Create a few y nodes.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;create (y:y{id: 1}) return y;
create (y:y{id: 2}) return y;
...
&lt;p&gt;Thanks&lt;/p&gt;

        </summary>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I just want to know if this is a bug or it's really what it's suppose to show. Thank you!

Comment: What do you think may be a bug here?

Comment: Google Chrome, by default, doesn't handle RSS feeds but shows their contents in the browser instead. At best this is a *Chrome issue* then.

Answer (score 4):

It's an [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). Depending on your browser you'll get a dump of the XML or you'll get a nice interface for it. Here's a screenshot of Firefox:

> [image: Firefox interface for an RSS feed]